# Deploying Qt with Mac OS X app - how not to load any plugins?

Tags: macos, qt, plugins, deployment, qt4.8

I want to package Qt 4.x shared libraries together with my application so that users do not have to install the Qt frameworks. With a build script, I correctly patched all my Qt dependencies and ensured that none are loaded from my Qt installation in `/Library/Frameworks` anymore (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15947403/245706)).

However now I'm running into problems because at some point during initialization, the plugin `/Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/bearer/libqcorewlanbearer.dylib` is loaded:

```
$ export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1
$ cd /path/to/my.app/Contents/MacOS
$ ./myappexecutable

dyld: loaded: /path/to/executable
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/A/QTKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
dyld: loaded: /path/to/my.app/Contents/MacOS/./../Qt/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
dyld: loaded: /path/to/my.app/Contents/MacOS/./../Qt/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
dyld: loaded: /path/to/my.app/Contents/MacOS/./../Qt/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/4/QtOpenGL
dyld: loaded: /path/to/my.app/Contents/MacOS/./../Qt/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit
dyld: loaded: /path/to/my.app/Contents/MacOS/./../Qt/phonon.framework/Versions/4/phonon
dyld: loaded: /path/to/my.app/Contents/MacOS/./../Qt/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
[...]
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL
dyld: loaded: /path/to/my.app/Contents/MacOS/./../Qt/QtDBus.framework/Versions/4/QtDBus
dyld: loaded: /path/to/my.app/Contents/MacOS/./../Qt/QtXml.framework/Versions/4/QtXml
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/Versions/A/CoreServicesInternal
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/PlugIns/csparser.bundle/Contents/MacOS/csparser
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ColorSyncDeprecated.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Extensions/ATIRadeonX3000GLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ATIRadeonX3000GLDriver
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGPUSupport.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelHD3000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHD3000GraphicsGLDriver
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources//GLRendererFloat.bundle/GLRendererFloat
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libcldcpuengine.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Versions/A/DiskImages
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreFSCache.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/DiscRecording.framework/Versions/A/DiscRecording
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaKit.framework/Versions/A/MediaKit
dyld: loaded: /Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins/bearer/libqcorewlanbearer.dylib
[^^^ this one is problematic as it loads global Qt libraries, see below]
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework/Versions/A/CoreWLAN
dyld: loaded: /Library/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork
dyld: loaded: /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7fc2d260b280) is not the object's thread (0x7fc2d4245fd0).
Cannot move to target thread (0x7fc2d260b280)
```

That plugin references the globally installed Qt frameworks and then I essentially have two sets of Qt binaries loaded, causing all kinds of trouble.

Now my question is: Where is that plugin loaded (couldn't find any binary containing "wlanbearer") and how do I ensure no plugins are automatically loaded from my application?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Normally if you use macdeployqt to fix your dependencies, the plugins that are loaded by the Qt libraries get copied over as well.

Comment: Nice, seems exactly what I'm seeing right now :)
Any chance you remember if you solved it back then?

Comment: I included the plugin because I couldn't find out how to disable loading it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to substitute plugins path right after QApplication initialization:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QCoreApplication::removeLibraryPath(QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::PluginsPath));
QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("../../PlugIns");
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This does not avoid loading the plugin, but just replaced the qt.conf file by code.

Comment: In my case plugins are bundled by macdeployqt, but extern plugins from the Qt installation are loaded first. The qt.conf file contains the correct path to the plugin directory in the bundle.